# Calculating 2^n in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, big-o, memoization

Without using bit shifts, is there any way to calculate 2^n in O(n) time?

I was considering a solution using memoization as I will always calculate from lower n first. 
ie

```
d = dict()
def pwr2(n):
    if n == 0:
       return 1
    if n == 1:
       return 2
    if n in d:
       return d[n]
    d[n] = 2 * pwr2(n-1)
    return d[n]
```

But I'm not quite sure what the complexity would be.

EDIT: I should add that I am using this a part of an algorithm to convert binary to decimal in faster than O(n^2) time. As part of my divide-and-conquer algorithm, I have to multiply by increasing powers of two, hence why I tried memoizing.

EDIT2: Just posting my full algorithm here to help resolve confusion
pwr2dict = dict()

```
def karatsuba(x, y):
    // use karatsuba's algorithm to multiply x*y


def pwr2(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    if n in pwr2dict:
        return pwr2dict[n]
    pwr2dict[n] = karatsuba(pwr2(n-1),2)
    return pwr2dict[n]


def binToDec(b):
    if len(b) == 1:
        return int(b)
    n = int(math.floor(len(b)/2))
    top = binToDec(b[:n])  # The top n bits
    bottom = binToDec(b[n:])  # The bottom n bits
    return bottom + karatsuba(top, pwr2(len(b)-n))

print binToDec("10110") // Prints 22
```

Comment: The complexity of your memoized solution is the same as a solution without memoization, as no result is ever reused. Both are still O(n), though, if multiplication is constant time. (It isn’t.)

Comment: What is your divide-and-conquer algorithm? Maybe it’s better to ask about that.

Comment: If the n in O(n) is the number of bits in the n in 2^n, then you are actually asking for an O(log n) algorithm. Or to put it another way, an algorithm to compute 2^k in O(n) time where n is the number of bits in k

Comment: Is this a question about Python, or is it abstract? If abstract, what computational model are you using?

Comment: @minitech -- I added the full algorithm.

Comment: @Anonymous - It's abstract, but I've been using python to sketch out the algorithm for testing purposes.

Comment: If abstract, what RAM model are you using? Bytes? How should bigints be represented? If you choose the representation to be, for example, an array of bytes with a sign bit, then the answer is easily O(n) since you can just construct the result without doing any multiplications.

Comment: Note: What you're doing isn't a conversion from binary to decimal. The conversion to decimal happens in the `print` call, which calls `int.__str__` or `long.__str__`, and that's going to use a naive algorithm. You'll need to implement your own logic for converting the base to decimal to avoid that.

Comment: @user2357112 Hasn't my binary string input been converted to decimal by the time function returns?

Comment: @GautamGupta: No. It has been converted to a Python int or long, which internally uses some form of binary representation.

Comment: How does Karatsuba help multiplication by 2? Are there algorithms for evaluating powers other than iterated multiplication by the original number?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are overthinking your problem. `2^n` simply means multiply two with itself `n` times. So a simple loop from 1 to `n` will do the trick :-)

```
r = 2
for 1 to n do
  r = r * 2
end
```

This is solution run in `O(n)`, the real problem with calculating `2^n`, is that on a moderne computer you'll hit the architectures word length for quite a small `n`, like 32, 64 or 128. And then you have to use an arbitrary length integer, which might not give you quite `O(n)` time, but that's a different question :-) in theory, it can be done, trivially, in `O(n)`.

**EDIT**

Ok, so if I understand you correctly you have a very long binary string, and you want to convert it to decimal.

I'd implement it as follows:

Put the binary string, of length `n` into an array, `s` (could be bitmap to save space, could be string in a programming language which supports those). Reverse the string so LSB is at index 0 (if not already the case).

```
e := 1
r := 0
for i := 0 to (n - 1) 
  if s[i] = 1
    r := r + e
  end
  e := e * 2
end
```

Reversing the string can be done in `O(n)`, the the pseudo code only have a single loop from `0` to `n - 1`, so that too is in `O(n)`. The bit string reversing can be avoid to at bit of simple arithmetic in the loop. And not that `r` must be an arbitrary length integer typer.

Comment: And this is exactly an _O(n)_ solution, as the OP stated.

Comment: My issue with that is that multiplication is O(n) for an n-bit number is O(n^2), no? I was given a hint to use Karatsuba's algorithm for multiplication as we can get O(n^1.59) instead

Comment: The memory used to represent 2^n in binary grows linearly, not exponentially, with n. Literally linearly, since 2^n has n bits.

Comment: While the original form of this answer was a valid solution to the original form of the question, neither the original form nor the edited form of the answer properly address the slowdown that arises when dealing with arbitrary-precision integers. Neither `r := r + e` nor `e := e * 2` can be treated as running in constant time, so the loop cannot be treated as running in linear time.

Comment: @user23571122, that's true multiplication of arbitrary length integers is in general `O(n^2)` (or `O(n log n log log n)` if you do something clever), however since you multiplying a power of two, with a power of two, you can to the multiplication in constant time.

Comment: First, that requires bitshifts, which we're not allowed to do. Second, it's still not constant time; it takes time proportional to the size of the integer, so the whole loop still takes O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it in O(1) time. Multiply 2 by itself means doing a left shift by n-1 bits. Or left shifting 1 by n bits.

Your problem can be solved by the following.
`long k = 2 << n-1.`
or
`long k = 1 << n.`

Isn't it simple?

**EDIT**
I realized that it is to be done without bit shift. Still you do not need O(n) time. Can be done in O(logn)

```
private int power(int x, int n) {

    if (n == 1)
        return x;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        int power = power(x, n / 2);
        return power * power;
    } 

    else{
        int power = power(x, (n - 1) / 2);
        return x * power * power;
    }
}
```

Learn more about recursion [Recursion](http://techieme.in/recursion/)

Comment: still it is not O(log n)! really you could do x * power * power in O(1)?

Comment: I am not sure how you see asymptotic analysis. But yes x * power * power is a simple multiplication function, given the three numbers are present. Also, the time taken by this mathematical operation is not dependent on the input n. So multiplication is constant time operation. I agree that the constant might be a bigger one, but a constant. No matter if the value of n is 10 or 1 million, multiplying three numbers will be O(1) w.r.t the power n to which I want to raise a number.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it in `Time = T(f(n)) + T(g(n))` where `f(n)` is the time taken to construct a binary number of `n` binary-digits, and `g(n)` is the time taken to convert that number to decimal.

[**Test Code Online**](http://ideone.com/wWmGsu)

```
public BigInteger pow_2 (int n)
{
    String binary = "1";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) binary += "0"; // f(n)
    return new BigInteger(binary, 2); // g(n)
}
```

And because of compiler optimization, `f(n)` will get `T(f(n))` with `Θ(1)`.

As for `g(n)`, which represent `BigInteger(value,radix)` constructor, `g(n)` based on how many binary digits there are, where `2^n` in binary is a number that has `n+1` digits.

Comment: While including the time for base conversion would seem to be pushing it, one could look in the opposite direction: tasked to compute 2 to the nth power with no output representation specified, picking ld(n) yield O(1).

Comment: @greybeard yes, we can just return the binary. for small values of n, we can just write it as a value directly like `long r = 0x00..001` by bit-operation, which is `O(1)`, for `n <= 62` since `2^63 > Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @greybeard the essential issue here, is that if all the zeroes within the range of `2^n` in the solution exist in our hand (like if we define a primitive int or long variable) then we can just flip nth bit to get `2^n`